# Postgresql says column doesnt exist for any column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have created a table using following query

```
CREATE TABLE public.pg_subscription 
(
    id uuid DEFAULT public.uuid_generate_v4() NOT NULL,
    user_id uuid NOT NULL,
    pg_subscription_plan_id uuid,
    count integer DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL,
    authentication_url text,
    rp_id text,
    status public.pg_subscription_type DEFAULT 'created'::public.pg_subscription_type,
    created_timestamp timestamp with time zone,
    next_billing_date timestamp with time zone
);
```

I used this query to create this table using PgAdmin 4 and any insert query results into "column not exists" error. Any column I use as a first in the list of columns it will give the same error , so this is not specific to a column.

Not able to understand why this happening, any pointers are appreciated.

edit :

```
CREATE TYPE public.pg_subscription_type AS ENUM (
    'created',
    'authenticated',
    'active',
    'pending',
    'halted',
    'paused',
    'resumed',
    'cancelled'
);
```

This is the query that fails

```
insert into pg_subscription(user_id,id,pg_subscription_plan_id,count,authentication_url,rp_id,status,created_timestamp,next_billing_date)
    values ('shjkhfkhf','kdjfkd','dhfhfkh',0,'dfjdfh','kdff',1566656,7878787)
```

And this is the error

> ERROR:  column "user_id" of relation "pg_subscription" does not exist
> LINE 1: insert into pg_subscription(user_id,id,pg_subscription_plan,...
> ^
> SQL state: 42703
> Character: 29

Also this database exists on other server and working just fine this appeared on new server after extracting the schema via backup and restored with the help of PgAdmin sql tool.
Thanks

Comment: `public.pg_subscription_type`  definition is missing in the question.

Comment: Can you share a sample failing `insert` statement and the error you're getting for it?

Comment: @Mureinik here is the exact error added to the question, also I tried this using PgAdmin

Comment: Use single quotes for string constants, not double quotes.

Comment: the column `pg_subscription_plan` really doesn't exist - you have `pg_subscription_plan_id`. Additionally, `count` is a reserved word and should be escaped.

Comment: @Mureinik thats a typo but this doesnt answer the question because this database exists and working on other server already I took the schema and tried replicating it and its not working . So I am more confused

Comment: @Mureinik also I have used single quotes too I know this and it still throws same error, also I tried changing order of columns and whichever is first it gives error to that

Answer (score 1):

- avoid keywords as column names
- don't assign random text to UUIDs
- Don't prefix your object names with `pg_`;  it is reserved for the catalogs

Works here:

---

```
\i tmp.sql

-- DROP TYPE public.omg_subscription_type ;
CREATE TYPE omg_subscription_type AS ENUM (
    'created'
    , 'authenticated'
    , 'active'
    , 'pending'
    , 'halted'
    , 'paused'
    , 'resumed'
    , 'cancelled'
);

-- DROP TABLE public.omg_subscription ;
CREATE TABLE omg_subscription
(
    -- id uuid DEFAULT public.uuid_generate_v4() NOT NULL
    id uuid DEFAULT public.gen_random_uuid() NOT NULL
    , user_id uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT public.gen_random_uuid() NOT NULL
    , omg_subscription_plan_id uuid DEFAULT public.gen_random_uuid() NOT NULL
    , zcount integer DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL
    , authentication_url text
    , rp_id text
    , status omg_subscription_type DEFAULT 'created'::omg_subscription_type
    , created_timestamp timestamp with time zone
    , next_billing_date timestamp with time zone
);

insert into omg_subscription( zcount, authentication_url, rp_id, status, created_timestamp, next_billing_date)
                        values ( 0, 'dfjdfh', 'wtf', 'created'::omg_subscription_type , '2020-09-04'::timestamp , '2021-09-04'::timestamp )
        ;

SELECT * FROM omg_subscription
        ;
```

---

Result:

---

```
DROP SCHEMA
CREATE SCHEMA
SET
CREATE TYPE
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 1
                  id                  |               user_id                |       omg_subscription_plan_id       | zcount | authentication_url | rp_id | status  |   created_timestamp    |   next_billing_date    
--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------+--------------------+-------+---------+------------------------+------------------------
 41bed520-1867-4533-a574-f98db988ab2c | ec05f6d2-754e-4348-a696-24eefe2521c2 | 6ce3bc7d-3a05-47b5-9ab4-a551f582539f |      0 | dfjdfh             | wtf   | created | 2020-09-04 00:00:00+02 | 2021-09-04 00:00:00+02
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably schema name is missing

```
insert into public.pg_subscription(..
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved it and the problem was genuine, all above answers are generic, the problem was different and totally unexpected, I had to prefix the table name with "public" and it worked . This was needed because of "pg_" prefix .